# JavaMail vs Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, jakarta-mail

Trying to send an email with an attachment using JavaMail. If you view the letter through a browser, then everything works fine. If you view the letter through Outlook, the letter comes in the form of a file with the extension .dat. Tell me what is the problem? How can this be fixed?

My code

```
public class MailMail{

    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    private SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage;

    public void setSimpleMailMessage(SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage) {
        this.simpleMailMessage = simpleMailMessage;
    }

    public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender mailSender) {
        this.mailSender = mailSender;
    }

    void sendMAil4() throws EmailException {

        EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
        attachment.setPath("C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\отправка\\file.xlsx");
        attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
        attachment.setDescription("Picture of John");
        attachment.setName("John");

        MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
        email.setHostName("smtp.yandex.ru");
        email.setSmtpPort(465);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("from@yandex.ru", "12345678"));
        email.setFrom("from@yandex.ru");
        email.setSubject("TestMail");
        email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
        email.addTo("to@yandex.ru");

        email.attach(attachment);

        email.send();

    }
}
```

Comment: You have tagged this JavaMail, but the API you're using is not the JavaMail API, but an API built on top of the JavaMail API. Which API is it? And if you're using your own homegrown API, then please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when older email clients (e.g. Outlook 2007 and 2010) use the old **RFC2047** standard for filename handling of attachments. Special characters in the filename won't be recognized and the attachment will then be renamed with the **.bin** or **.dat** extension. The newer **RFC2231** standard requires that any spaces and special characters in the attachment filenames should be converted into their MIME equivalent. You could either upgrade your Outlook client, or you could make sure that the filenames don't contain ***spaces or special characters***.

- [With JavaMail API 1.5.6, this problem will occur with names longer than 60 bytes](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4052611)
- [How to Prevent Winmail.dat Attachments from Being Sent in Outlook](https://www.lifewire.com/prevent-sending-winmail-dat-attachments-1173717)
- [JavaMail - How to Send E-Mail w/ Attachements](https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/javamail/send-e-mail-with-attachment-in-java)